# creating an email based on another record

Tags: email-template, apex-email-service

I want to be able to share the contents of a field from a particular record with an email recipient. Rather than going to the record and copying the field value, I would like to be able go the the record and click a button that will take the contents of the field and create an email that I can then select the contact for. Is there standard functionality that I can leverage or would I need to program it?

Answer (score 2):

Bartley, I'm going to assume you are still a point-and-click man so here's an elaboration on Girbot's answer

Assume we have an Object called `Foo__c`. It has standard and custom fields, notably `Bar__c` for purposes of the example

**Step 1** - Create an Email Template (text, HTMl, VF, doesn't matter). Use a merge field from Foo__c to show a value from the record

[image]

**Step 2** - Create a custom button via URL hacking using @Girbot's [link](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=087300000006tqzAAA) for guidance

[image]

Add the custom button the page layout of `Foo__c`. Note it is a detail page button

**Step 3** - Go to any `Foo__c` detail page, click the new custom button. The result will include the merge field and allow the user to choose a Contact

[image]

Comment: that's great to see that it can be done in declarative fashion, much appreciated. Would you have done written code instead yourself?

Comment: In the simple use case you mentioned; I would have done the URL hacking as above. If the target object Foo__c has a Lookup to Contact, then you can prepopulate the ContactId as well on the send to email page.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the detail you could potentially use a URL button. Explained in detail here:
https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=087300000006tqzAAA

Basically you pass the field into the url to populate your email.